# Database Schema for Individual and Group accounts(Like Facebook Users and Pages)

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm trying to create a schema, which is very similar to part of what Facebook does,so i will explain with that as an example as it would be easier.

Just like Facebook, we have Users and Facebook Pages. Both can publish posts, follow each other and the users have a feed page where they can see the posts of the entities they have followed(User or Pages)

The page is managed by group of accounts(page moderators),the posts they make will appear as posts from the page.

How do i go about this?

What i thought of

1. Create a user table and Page Table. User table have a column called group_id which will map to the Page Table id for the moderator accounts, since both are kind of similar this makes sense.
2. Making separate User and Moderator Tables

However with the above approach i probably would have make two separate tables for posts as author_id will be different, users will have user_id and pages have page_id.

Also thinking of doing something like this for the Follow table

```
follower-user_followed-page_followed
1-2-NULL
1-NULL-5
```

I know this is not the kind of ideal solution and will be problematic to retrieve the user_id and page_id from the Follow table, do a query on posts from user post table and then again on brand post table, merge them all and show it on the feed,but i'm unable to wrap my head around this any other way.Searched for Facebook schema, but was unable to find with Pages in it. Please any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different tables for different entities.

1. Users
2. Groups
3. Moderators (contains id of corresponding users and moderated by them groups id)
4. Followers (contains id of users and followed by them groups)

Tables 3 and 4 provides such called "many-to-many" relationship (multiple users can follow multiple groups), as databases support only one-to-many or one-to-one relationship from the box

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input, had a question. In the Followers table, the user can follow both other users as well as groups, do you recommend to put both of it in the same table or different table?

Comment: Users can follow user, and thus, when other user follows back, isn't it called friendship in terms of social networks? If so, then I'd rather to divide following groups and users relationships in different tables.